# HTML required Field doesnt work on IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my custom build HTML form

```
<form id="i-recaptcha" action="#" method="POST">

<input class="first_name_popup" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required="required">

<input class="last_name_popup" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
<input class="email_popup" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" required="required">

<input class="submit_button_popup" id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="GET A FREE CONSULTATION!">
</form>
```

how can i make this work on IOS? right now im getting so many blank forms submitted.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, it should just be *required* not *required=''* **edit** - see Scott's comment, my comment is incorrect.

Comment: required="true" should work.

Comment: @Adam The W3C states that Boolean attributes can have a value (although it is generally ignored by the browser). In those cases, they recommend using the attribute name, as in `required="required"`.

Comment: @A.Meshu As long as `required` is present, it will work. The value is irrelevant because it's a Boolean attribute.

Comment: @A.Meshu Are we talking about XHTML? Does anyone write that (intentionally) anymore? And, if you do care about XHTML, and agree that `required="required"` is the way to do, then why did you recommend `required="true"`?

Comment: hey guys. i already tried these options
required="required"
required="True" and no luck!.

for some reason the HTML editor that comes with the theme doesnt let me only use the plain word required. it automatically adds =""  when i save it.